# Usage of Enum Types

Tags: c, enums, header-files

I am making a program with an enumerated type that is included in my header file.

```
enum Type {
    UNKNOWN, STRING, FLOAT, LONG, INT, CHAR
};
typedef enum Type Type_t;

/*
 * Returns the Type_t of the data under the column with the name given. If the
 * column name is not recognized, UNKNOWN is returned.
 */
Type_t column_type(char *column);
```

In my program, I am using it as

```
enum  Type_t typeer=column_type(lineRow[headerIndex]);
            if(typeer==LONG)
            {
                *((long *) container[j]) = *((long *)lineRow[headerIndex]);
                long * min,*max;
            }
```

I have seen examples over the internet and tried to use techniques. I am new to enums. Please highlight what I am doing wrong.

Output :

```
main.c:352:19: note: forward declaration of 'enum Type_t'
            enum  Type_t typeer=column_type(lineRow[headerIndex]);
                  ^
main.c:353:24: error: use of undeclared identifier 'LONG'
            if(typeer==LONG)
```

Sometimes, it says that I have incomplete type enum Type_t, I have tried using Type_t alone but could not work out

Comment: why did you typedef a enum?

Comment: yes I defined it as Type_t.

Comment: It makes it easier for me to use it. However, even if I am using it without the typedef I am getting the same error (use of undeclared identifier)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `enum  Type_t`, either use `enum Type` or `Type_t`.

`Type_t` is an alias to `enum Type` there is no `enum Type_t` in your program. Also if you are declaring the type in a header, make sure this header is included in the source files where you using it.

Comment: I have included the header. Moreover, I have tried using that Type_t. But, it says use of undeclared identifier Type_t and LONG